# Laravel: Display array item containing certain value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I passed an array from my controller to my view like so:

```
    $Client_Package_Items = DB::table('client__package__items')
    ->join('treatments', 'client__package__items.treatment_id', '=', 'treatments.id')
    ->get();

    return view('Sales.show')
    ->with('Client_Package_Items', $Client_Package_Items);
```

I want to make a loop that will only contain certain data from this array when I click on different buttons containing an ID value that is in this array.

This is my view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="redeem{{$c->id}}">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">  
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header bg-success text-white">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Top up Package Serial No. {{$c->id}}</h4>
            {{Form::hidden('client_package_id', $c->id)}}
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row mt-3">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @foreach($Client_Package_Items as $cpi)
                                    {{$cpi->treatment}}
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            {{Form::hidden('sale_type_id', 3)}}
            {{Form::hidden('client_id', $Clients->id)}}
            {{Form::submit('Top-up', ['class'=>'btn btn-success submitBtn',])}}
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to check $c->id against the array and show only the array of data containing $c->id.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add selectraw to your query

```
$Client_Package_Items = DB::table('client__package__items')
                            ->join('treatments', 'client__package__items.treatment_id', '=', 'treatments.id')
                            ->SelectRaw('client_package_items.id as id ,...') //add this
                            ->get();
```